# Accessing ASP.NET C# Eval Databound Object within Object

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

I have a rather tricky situation. I am using an ASP:Repeater which is bound to a SOAP datasource returning the below object structure.

```
Path: Array[6]
0: Object
   Direction: "Departing"
   Message: ""
   Operator: "myciti"
   RouteColor: "#a7a9ac"
   RouteName: "Airport"
       Stop: Object
           Name: "JFK"
           Location: Object
   Name: "Airport"
   __proto__: Object
   Time: "07:10"
   Type: ""
   Vehicle: ""
```

I can easily access all the first tier variables, such as "Time" by using Eval as such:

```
  <%# Eval("Time")%>
```

My problem is how would I access the nested objects still using EVAL from the ASPX page? For example how would I get to the "Name" value of the "Stop" object within this array which has the value "JFK"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:
     `<%# Eval("Stop.Name")%>`

Answer (score 2):

Eval is just a shortcut to obtain a property by name. It won't help you in some cases. Like for example, what if your object RouteName sometimes returns null.

You need to use:

```
<%# Container.DataItem.RouteName.Stop.Name %>
```

Container.DataItem is an object so you can access just about any property from it.

A better way would be to Cast that object into a more meaningful instance:

```
<%# Ctype(Container.DataItem, ReturnedSOAPObjectRecord).RouteName.Stop.Name %>
```

This method gives you the ability to check for nulls.

```
<%# IF(Ctype(Container.DataItem, ReturnedSOAPObjectRecord).RouteName IsNot Nothing, Ctype(Container.DataItem, ReturnedSOAPObjectRecord).RouteName.Stop.Name, "No Stop" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: Carlos, I was just reading through your methods and think you may have made a syntax error in your third method.